Problems with dates and xlsx
I am exporting a table to excel using XLSX v0.15.6. When I export the table the date fields are changed and I don't understand why. The table is created with php5.6 and html but to export it it uses javascript and jquery v1.10.2 . I'm working on ubuntu 20.04 and Libre Officce.
This is the function
function exportExcel() {
        /** 
         * * Filename 
         * */
        var fileName = 'Acc ' + currentDate + '.xls'

        /**
         * * Get the table  
         * */
        const table = document.getElementById('table');

        /**
         ** Clone the table and remove unnecessary celds from de new table
         */
        var cloneTable = table.cloneNode(true);
        jQuery(cloneTable).find('.noPrint').remove();

        /**
         * * Print all date celds for checking 
         * */
        jQuery(cloneTable).find('.date').text(function(i, originalDate) {
            console.log(originalDate)
        })

        /** 
         * * Remove spaces   
         * */
        jQuery(cloneTable).find('td').text(function(i, originalText) {
            const newText = originalText.trim()
            return newText
        })

        /** 
         * * Create the wb
         * */
        const wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(cloneTable, {
            sheet: 'Hoja 1'
        });

        /**
         * * Exportar the file 
         * */
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
    }

This is a part of the table

And this is the console output corresponding to the top

As you can see the values correspond.
This is the output in excel

Some formats don't match and some dates don't match either and I don't understand why.

You should probably use ISO format dates, YYYY-MM-DD. Otherwise its heuristics won't parse the dates properly.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.
